# Saving a file in application directory from the application

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, matlab

I needed to add a new toolbox to MATLAB. I did so by adding it to the path specified. When I tried to save the `pathdef.m` file however, I was told that I could not save directly into the default file-location, `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\toolbox\local`, but had to save it elsewhere and have it in my current working directory. However, I don't really want to copy the file to each working directory whenever I want to use that particular toolbox.

I understand that the issue is that MATLAB does not have the requisite permissions to save the file directly there. I was able to work around it by saving it elsewhere and then replacing the file with admin rights, but in case I want to do it again in the future, can I give the permission to MATLAB directly in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend following the advice provided my MathWorks in [this support document](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-5YQCPR/index.html?product=ML), as I'll paraphrase loosely here, assuming I've understood it correctly:

1. Use `pathtool` to determine the current search path.
2. Put a startup.m somewhere in that search path that invokes the pathdef.m that you want to have invoked

Comment: Thanks! It's still a workaround I guess, but it does the trick. :)